# Android Studio Instrumented Test fails with "DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big."

Tags: java, android, android-studio

On Android Studio 3.3.2 with java --version of 11.0.2, I can't run an instrumented test without this error:

```
DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
```

Googling turned up something about certificates but I was not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this issue before, and assumed it was related to the keystore being corrupted. I didn't dig too deeply into it, but I was able to make the error go away by regenerating my Android debug.keystore

```
# close Android Studio
cd ~/.android
mv debug.keystore debug.keystore.backup
rm debug.keystore.lock
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```